# Many col-md* inside one row, is it correct?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

It works in chrome, but does not display well in firefox.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><strong>Name</strong></div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-6">test</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><strong>Sex</strong></div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-6">Male</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><strong>Age</strong></div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-6">16</div>
    
</div>
</div>
    
      
  </div>
```

chrome

[image]

Firefox 47(MacOSX):

[image: firefox SO]

Comment: what is problem ? share screenshot

Comment: Are you sure ? i just runned it in firefox and it's working,  Your sample code seems to not be enough to reproduce the problem

Comment: Opened this http://www.bootply.com/xqz4nhqnDZ in Firefox, same result as in Chrome (on Windows). Perhaps it is a Mac thing, try looking at the default style elements in mac.

Comment: above bootply sample still display mess in firefox/mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use `label` tag right ?

if yes than add this css

```
label{margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: No, I'm not using label. But even if I use label and and this css, the display in firefox still messes

Comment: Its inside panel and container-fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Firefox might be operating in Quirk mode where the layout is non-standard and may not be correctly displayed.
Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` to operate in full html standards mode.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode

Also try clearing the cache. See the link below:

> https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly correct. [Bootstrap allows](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping) to use many blocks in one row. This is a useful feature:

> **Column wrapping**
>   If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.